# Can we edit WP-bakery template using the divi builder?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpbakery, divi

my client's requirement is to add a wp-bakery template and make changes using Divi builder, but I haven't found any relevant articles/tutorials related to this. I'm not sure whether this will work or not

Answer (score 0):

No this won't work.
It's either WP Bakery or Divi.
You'll have to redo the template in Divi by hands.
There are no converters.